# Test if object contains tap: false

Tags: javascript

I am receiving either of these two objects:

```
{alarmId: "2559"}
{alarmId: "2559", tap: false}
```

and I wish to do something like this:

```
if (tap(o)) {
    console.log("tap");
}
else {
    console.log("not tap");
}
```

So if tap is undefined for the object, tap should return `true` and even if `tap:true` just to be on the safe side. Else I wish to return `false` from the tap function. How should I write the tap function?

Comment: So what is your question? Detect if the object has a `tap` property, or writing a tap function? What do you need the `tap()` function to do?

Comment: what is hard to see if an object has a key and read its value?  `console.log(myObject.tap)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function tap (o) {
  return (typeof o.tap === "undefined" || o.tap === true);
}
```

Only `true` and non-defined values pass.  (`false`, `"foo"` and `42` all return false)

Comment: `typeof` is not a function. Technically, those paren aren't necessary.

Comment: `tap({})` will return true.

Comment: @FaouziOudouh The question stated "... tap should return true [...] just to be on the safe side."  Hence this does seem appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the function this way:

```
function tap (o) {
  return (typeof o["tap"] != "undefined");
}
```

This returns `true` if the object has `tap`.

Comment: I want true returned from tap when tap is true or not defined.

Comment: @Baz Okay, got it.

Answer (score -2):

Just use:

```
if(o.tap === false)
    console.log('tap is false')       // tap is the value `false`
else
    console.log('tap is not `false`') // tap can be anything: any value, or `undefined`.
```

Check for the value you want, don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

It can be as simple as:

```
return o.tap === false;
```